# Selenium Web Driver Stale Element Reference exception for tabbed UI

Tags: java, angularjs, selenium-webdriver

```
WebDriverWait w = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
w.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.linkText("Credit Card")));
```

Link "Credit Card" is an UI tab.
I am not able to click on the link.
I get Stale Element Reference Exception
[image]
Html

```html
<div class="paymnt_nav" ng-show="$parent.mobileInfo.isMobile==false || closePaymentMode != true">
  <ul>
    <li class="ng-hide"
        ng-click="viewParams.webPaymentTabs='SC';resetCards('');removeBinOffer(true,true);checkOffer('storedCard',paymentMerchant.storeCardDTOList[0].cardToken,0,'',true);storeCardSelect();"
        ng-show="viewParams.savedCards==true">

    <li class="ng-scope"
        ng-if="paymentMerchant.paymentOption.cc !='-1' && paymentMerchant.paymentOption.cc !=null">
      <a class="''"
         ng-class="{'active':viewParams.webPaymentTabs=='CC','':viewParams.webPaymentTabs!='CC'}" 
         ng-click="$parent.closePaymentMode = true;viewParams.webPaymentTabs='CC';paymentObject.paymentType='CC';resetCards('creditcard');removeBinOffer(true,true);handleSpecificConvenienceFee();_handlingCashBackScenario({})">
    </li>

    <li class="ng-scope" 
        ng-if="paymentMerchant.paymentOption.db !='-1' && paymentMerchant.paymentOption.db !=null">

    <li class="ng-scope"
        ng-click="$parent.closePaymentMode = true;viewParams.webPaymentTabs='NB';paymentObject.paymentType='NB';resetCards('netbanking');removeBinOffer(true,true);autoSelectNetBanking();_handlingCashBackScenario({});checkForNBStatus();" 
        ng-if="paymentMerchant.paymentOption.nb !='-1' && paymentMerchant.paymentOption.nb !=null">

    <li class="ng-scope" ng-if="paymentMerchant.loyltyEnabled==true">
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: can you please post html code part of that div? Also did you try by increasing wait time? like 30 , 60 seconds?

Comment: where is linktext a href for credit card? in html?

Comment: Please post some valid HTML and properly formatted. Also, please show the code that actually does the click.

Comment: Increasing the wait time isn't going to help with a stale element reference.

Comment: driver.findElement(By.linkText("Credit Card")).click();

Comment: How to click a on a angular js tab using selenium web driver?

Answer (score 0):

You should be placing IDs on these major UI elements for purposeful selenium testing. Looking in the DOM for link text is not good practice and may cause instability in your tests. Try adding IDs and finding the element by ID.

Comment: Cannot add any ID's as it is third party payment html page

Comment: So you're writing tests for third party functionality? Your testing boundary should always stop just short of the pass-off to any third party.